# Why can't I encrypt the second word?

Tags: c, encryption, scanf

I have been trying to come up with a code to encrypt a string. I've traced this code so many times but can't find the error. It only encrypts the first word and fails at the second one.

I made it so that the exclamation mark is the terminator. Can you help please!

```
char word[50];
int i;
char str[50];
char c;

printf("enter word to decrypt: ");
scanf("%s", word);


for( i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    c = word[i];
    if (c == ' ') {
        str[i] = c;
        continue;
    }
    if (c == '!') {
        str[i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
    str[i] = word[i] + 1;
}
printf("Encrypted string is '%s'\n", str);
```

Comment: Read a bit about how `scanf` works...

Comment: do **not** try yourself on exercises like "encryption/decryption" right now, thats **far** too advanced for beginners and you wont learn much.

Comment: Not sure who upvotes these questions, even the tiniest debugging/tracing would have found the problem. I see no effort.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean that you give two (or more) words as input to a single [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) call? Then that won't work.

The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) `"%s"` format only reads single *space delimited* words. It can't read multiple space-delimited words using the `"%s"` format.

Either use a loop to read multiple words, or use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a whole line, or use a format which doesn't stop at space (such as `"%["`).

---

There are also other problems with the code as you show it. It can overflow the buffer if you input a single word of more than 49 characters. And the loop doesn't care about the actual length of the word and will go outside into uninitialized memory of the array `word`. Both of these will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s", word);` will stop reading the string when it hit into a whitespace.

Use `scanf("%49[^\n]", word);` (this won't include the newline character) or `fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);` (this will include the newline character if it exists) to read an entire line. Note that specifying the maximum length to read is important to avoid buffer overrun.

Another solution is using `getchar()` to read the characters directly to `c`. Note that assigning what is returned from `getchar()` directly to a variable having type `char` is bad because it will prevent from distinguishing `EOF` with characters.

```
int i;
char str[50];
char c;

printf("enter word to decrypt: ");
scanf("%s", word);


for( i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    int input = getchar();
    if (input == EOF) {
        str[i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
    c = input;
    if (c == ' ') {
        str[i] = c;
        continue;
    }
    if (c == '!') {
        str[i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
    str[i] = input + 1;
}
str[49] = '\0'; /* prevent it from accessing out-of-range for in case the input is too long */
printf("Encrypted string is '%s'\n", str);
```

Comment: since when a word contains a space? :)

Comment: Aerospaces contains a space ;-)

Comment: @FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy like cyberspace? :P

Comment: 1) "will stop reading the string when it hit into a whitespace." --> `scanf("%s", word);` ignores leading whitespace (does not stop) and continues reading.  Then in scans/saves non-white-space until it hit s a whitespace.  2) `scanf("%49[^\n]", word);` returns without changing `word` should the first character be a `'\n'`.  Check the function return value to detect.

Answer (score 1):

The **first problem** here, as I can see is in the looping condition. You're trying to use a fixed number of iteration like

```
 for( i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        c = word[i];
```

now, in case, the input for `word` is less than `50`, and `word` being an automatic local array variable, the content of the remaining elements will be indeterminate. Attempt to read that value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Once you have read an input, you can use `strlen()` to determine the *valid* index, and only read the contents from the *valid* indexes.

So, always initialize your local variables.

**Secondly**, you're *assuming* that the input word will contain a `!` character which you're depending on for the null-termination. In case, the input does not have a `!`, you will not have a null-terminator for your *string* and if used as a *string* later, may lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to memory overrun.

**Finally**, as others have already pointed out, if you're expecting `%s` to scan a *sentence with spaces* into `word`, well, `%s` does not work that way when used with `scanf()`. You may want to use `fgets()` then.

Comment: Might not be relevant, I see some hidden assumptions in the code, like `'!'`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Right, let me update my post about that. :)